# Why the error message "transaction too large" appears when I commit a transaction in TiDB?

Tags: database, tidb

When I commit a transaction that contains 100,000 rows in TiDB, the error message "transaction too large" appears. What is the limit for the transaction size in TiDB? Can I modify the limit using a certain parameter?

Answer (score 0):

As distributed transactions need to conduct two-phase commit and the bottom layer performs Raft replication, if a transaction is very large, the commit process would be quite slow and the following Raft replication flow is thus struck. To avoid this problem, the transaction size is limited:

- Each Key-Value entry is no more than 6MB
- The total number of Key-Value entry is no more than 300,000 rows
- The total size of Key-Value entry is no more than 100MB

It is not allowed to modify the limit.